# How do I add a new blank directory to a Git repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How can I add a blank directory (that contains no files) to a Git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not allow adding/tracking empty directories (as for, for example, **CVS**).

There is a common convention to add an empty file to the directory you need to track named `.gitkeep`.

You will remove this file if a meaningful file will be added to it.